# How to fix ct-ng menuconfig "Failed to create symbolic link ‘config’: Permission denied make: * [config] Error 1" when cross compiling for Raspberry?

Tags: 12.04, compiling, raspberrypi

I am currently trying to set up a cross compiler for Raspberry Pi using Ubuntu 13.04. I have been following the tutorial [How to build a cross compiler for your Raspberry Pi](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/).

I am running into an error that I cannot interpret or find any help with on Google). And I am running into a problem when trying to run `ct-ng menuconfig` (In step 2 of the second part). I am receiving the following error:

```
matt@ubuntu:/home/RPICC$ ct-ng menuconfig LN config ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘config’: Permission denied make: * [config] Error 1
```

Any ideas as to what this means?

Comment: `Permission denied` often means 'You forgot sudo'

Comment: I get the following error: 'matt@ubuntu:/home/RPICC$ sudo ct-ng menuconfig
[sudo] password for matt: 
sudo: ct-ng: command not found
matt@ubuntu:/home/RPICC$'

Comment: "ct-ng: command not found" means Crosstool-ng isn't installed. If it is necessary, you have to install it before you can launch "sudo ct-ng menuconfig". (try without ct-ng, maybe that works)

Comment: Step 4.  Make sure /opt/cross/bin is in your path, but with sudo, you get a different PATH, so either explicitly use the full path to the executable, or change sudo's path (not recommended).

Comment: Some interesting commentary about this can be found at: http://www.landley.net/notes-2009.html see the March 7,2009 entry